# Как построить полигон по линии?

Tags: gis, php, геокодирование, геометрия

Есть массив с координатами точек линии, например:

```
[[55.217949,34.309849], [55.218159,34.309731], [55.21862,34.308819], 
[55.219311,34.309971], [55.219879,34.31097], [55.222752,34.31599], 
[55.224361,34.31879], [55.224541,34.319031], [55.22464,34.319118], 
[55.224781,34.319172], [55.227039,34.319031], [55.22995,34.318741], 
[55.231541,34.31712], [55.232071,34.317051], [55.23357,34.31736]]
```

Необходимо вокруг линии построить полигон, а если точнее, то надо определить точки, по которым будет строиться полигон.

Нашёл на просторах интернета только вот это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771908/computing-a-polygon-that-surrounds-a-multi-point-line, но рабочее решение там так и отсутствует.

Написал вот такой метод, но он "рисует" совсем неправильный полигон - с пересечениями, какими-то дырами и т.д.

```
    public function pointsArea($points, $radius) {
    $count = count($points);
    $firstCoords = $points[0];
    $lastCoords = $points[$count - 1];

    $latDiff = 1/(112/$radius); //radius in km
    $lonDiff = 1/(64/$radius);

    $polygonPoints = array();       
    foreach ($points as $n => $point) {
        if ($n == 0) {
            $polygonPoints[] = array(($point[0] + $latDiff), $point[1]);
            $polygonPoints[] = array($point[0], ($point[1] + $lonDiff));
        }
        if (isset($points[$n + 1])) {
            $next = $polygonPoints[$n + 1];
            if ($next[0] - $point[0]) {
            
            }
        }
        $polygonPoints[] = array(floatval($point[0] + $latDiff), ($point[1] + $lonDiff));           
    }
    foreach ($points as $n => $point) {
        $polygonPoints[] = array(($point[0] - $latDiff), ($point[1] - $lonDiff));
    }
    $polygonPoints[] = $polygonPoints[0];
    return $polygonPoints;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение

Comment: А в чём заключается основная задача? Определение принадлежит ли какая-то точка этому полигону?

Comment: Примерно так. Нужно для запроса в mongo для вытаскивания всех точек в полигоне.

Comment: doroga.tv? или схожий проект?

Answer (score 1):

Если не секрет, а что за проектик такой ? )))
Просто можно средствами mongo сделать то же самое, только немного проще ))

Попробуй так:

```
rVector: function(pt1, pt2, width, angle) {
   var dx = pt2.y - pt1.y;
   var dy = pt2.x - pt1.x;
   var l = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dy, 2));
   if (!l)
      return pt1;

   var dxn = dx * Math.cos(angle) - dy * Math.sin(angle);
   var dyn = dx * Math.sin(angle) + dy * Math.cos(angle);

   var res = {};
   res.y = pt1.y + dxn * width / l;
   res.x = pt1.x + dyn * width / l;
   return res;
}

createPolygon: function (pt1, pt2, width1, width2) {
   var pts = [];
   pts.push(rVector(pt1, pt2, width1, 1));
   pts.push(rVector(pt1, pt2, width1, -1));
   pts.push(rVector(pt2, pt1, width2, 1));
   pts.push(rVector(pt2, pt1, width2, -1));
   return pts;
}
```

Ну и между 2-мя точками полилинии можно получить четырехугольник

*create_polygon(point1, point2, 2000, 2000)*

*create_polygon(point2, point3, 2000, 2000)*

*create_polygon(point3, point4, 2000, 2000)*

Пробуй.

P.S. Чтобы это работало для создания полигона по полилинии, которая была бы адекватна относительно земной поверхности, нужно сделать конверсию по по нужной проекции. Например, по меркатору.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, с углом всё всаёт на свои месте. В mongo, к сожалению, как сделать такое у меня не получилось найти, $near не умеет работать с линиями.=(
А проект внутренний в компании. Отображать точки продаж недалеко от дорог по маршрутам сотрудников.